# Linked List Warping

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a program which reads in a file, tokenizes each word and sends it to my linked list function. It checks it the word already exists if not it will place it in the front. My program works for small sized texts but then goes down hill rather quickly.

-This is the print after every insert (\n after print is finished)-

[image]

As can be seen it works but then parts of the list just start messing up like crazy its rather weird. I was provided with previous code which automatically tokenizes for me and calls upon insert every time search fails to find a match. Here is my Insert and Search code.

```
Boolean search(char *target)
{
assert(target != NULL);

struct NODE *temp = head;
Boolean result = false;

if ((temp != NULL) && (target != NULL))
{
    do
    {
        if (strcmp(temp->item, target) == 0)
        {
            result = true;
            temp = NULL;
        } else
            temp = temp->next;
    } while (temp != NULL);
}
else
if (target == NULL)
{
    printf("Error, no search target provided!\n");
}

return result;
}

Boolean insert(char *new_string)
{
assert(new_string != NULL);
Boolean result = false;

if (new_string != NULL)
{
    new = (struct NODE *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (new == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error, no memory left, consider smaller file");
    }
    else
    {
        new->item = new_string;
        new->next = head;
        head = new;
        result = true;
        printConcordance(); /*THIS PRINTS THE CURRENT LIST*/
    }
}
else
{
    printf("Error, string was not given!\n");
}
return result;
}
```

I am assuming I am doing something wrong with memory so I made sure all my Nodes are global variables and tried various things similar, but nothing I tried every works. Changing prints and even small edits cause huge effect which just baffles me further. I tried testing on Eclipse and Cygwin which both output differently.

Comment: and what did you see when you stepped through with yr debugger?

Comment: need to see way more. Show driving `main` and definition of `Node`

Comment: most likely culprit is that you are not copying the string to node, just copying the pointer. Do `new->item=strdup(new_string)` instead

Comment: Provide [mcve].

Comment: Perhaps the same buffer in the `main`(such caller) is divided like `strtok`.
So, it will be destroyed from the first word by input on the second and subsequent lines. It seems necessary to make a copy as suggested by @pm100.

Comment: What I ended up doing is *new->item = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(new_string) + 1);* followed by *strcpy(new->item, new_string);* and it seemed to of fixed my problem. I am not sure if this is the correct way of going about it, but it seemed to of worked.

Comment: Though again, I am not aware if that's the proper way of allocating memory *EDIT* I changed my code to just new->item = strdup(new_string) and it works fine. Thanks for the help guys